# How to check the AIC of the ARIMAmodel in R

Tags: r, sql-server

I use r script in SQL Server the below is my code in SQL Server to show the prediction by date. but I need just one time check the aic

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script

      @language = N'R'

     ,@script = N'library(forecast);

                                Data<- InputDataSet

                                month<- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)

                                mn<-month.abb[month]

                                DataMonth <- Data[ ,mn]

                                DataTS <- ts(c(t(DataMonth)), start = c(2012,01), end = c(2020,09), frequency =12)

                                ForecastArima <- forecast(auto.arima(DataTS))

                                ForecastArimadf <- data.frame(ForecastArima)'

     ,@input_data_1 = N'WITH CTE AS(SELECT YearDate as[Year],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12]  FROM (***  group by MONTH(msodurdate), year(msodurdate)) t )

                                                          AS Table1

                                                          PIVOT(SUM(MonthSales) FOR Monthdate IN([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) AS PVT)

                                      SELECT [Year],

                                       FROM CTE

                                      ORDER BY [Year] ASC'

     ,@output_data_1_name = N'ForecastArimadf'

    WITH RESULT SETS (("Point.Forecast" numeric(28,2) NOT NULL,

                                      "Lo.80" NUMERIC(28,2) NOT NULL,

                                      "Hi.80" NUMERIC(28,2) NOT NULL,

                                      "Lo.95" NUMERIC(28,2) NOT NULL,

                                      "Hi.95" NUMERIC(28,2) NOT NULL));
```

Now I want to check the AIC of the model but I do not know how to check it and show in output.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by assigning the result of `auto.arima()` to a variable, and then using `$`.
For example:

```
library(forecast)

myTSdata <- Seatbelts[,"DriversKilled"]
mymodel <- auto.arima(myTSdata)
```

To check the AIC :

```
mymodel$aic
#[1] 1530.405
```